# $\mathcal T (A)=B^{-1}AB$. Prove that $\mathcal T$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-isomorphism

$B$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix.

Define $\mathcal T :M_{n\times n}(\mathbf F)\to M_{n\times n}(\mathbf F)$
by

$\mathcal T (A)=B^{-1}AB$. 
Prove that $\mathcal T$ is an isomorphism.

I think we need to check $\mathcal T$ is $1-1$ and onto.

Comment: You just have to prove that it's 1-1, because $1-1\iff onto\iff bijective.$

Comment: @user657324 The map $x\mapsto e^x$ is $1-1$, but it is not onto, and not bijective.

Comment: @5xum: But $T$ is a linear application...

Comment: @5xum But $x\mapsto e^x$ isn't a linear map between vector spaces of the same (finite) dimension. Of course, one should probably show that $\mathcal T$ is linear.

Comment: @user657324 Then don't you think we should also prove that $\mathcal T$ is linear?

Comment: @Arthur My point exactly. It is *not* enough to show that $\mathcal T$ is 1-1. We must also show it is linear.

Comment: @5xum: Of course he does ! I just gave a comment, not an answer. Btw, $\mathcal T$ is obviously linear...

Comment: @5xum I think you can spot the part where I realized that that was the point of your original comment.

Comment: @user657324 as one of my professors said, "obvious" is not a word that should be in a student's vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $\mathcal T$ is $1-1$:

Take $X, Y\in$, and assume that $\mathcal T(X)=\mathcal T(Y)$. From that, prove that $X=Y$.

To prove that $\mathcal T$ is onto:

Take $X\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbf F)$ and find some $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbf F)$ such that $\mathcal T(A)=X$.

Comment: I know how to prove $1-1$, but I have no idea about onto. Can you show me that?

Comment: @Maggie Try writing down the equation $\mathcal T(X)=\mathcal T(Y)$, and from that equation, derive the equation $X=Y$.

Comment: I think we can also use $dim(M_{n\times n}(\mathbf F))=dim (null \mathcal T)+dim (range \mathcal T)$ to check onto:)

Comment: @Maggie Certainly. But you then have to show that $\mathcal T$ is a linear mapping.

Comment: Oh...I forgot that...

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces with the same dimension, all you need to prove is that $\mathcal T$ is injective *or* surjective. But it *is* injective:\begin{align}\mathcal T(A)=0&\iff B^{-1}AB=0\\&\iff A=B.0.B^{-1}\\&\iff A=0.\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn't it be $I$ instead of $0$?

Comment: No. Why? This is a linear map.